# how often to build a package?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's say that I have a node.py file inside my package/scripts folder. Do I need to rebuild the package everytime I modify my node.py file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363601/how-often-to-build-a-package-?/) by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 310 on 2020-10-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The short answer is NO.

you don't need to run catkin_make after every modification on your code

---

Originally posted by [Moneera Banjar](https://answers.ros.org/users/60255/moneera-banjar/) with karma: 108 on 2020-10-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you modify or write new Python nodes you need not build your package every time, because Python is an interpreted language and it need not be compiled. So you need to build your package only when you define service/actions/messages definitions, modify C++ codes. Have a look at all the things mentioned in CMakeLists.txt of a package to get an idea how makefile is generated by cmake.

---

Originally posted by [electrophod](https://answers.ros.org/users/43169/electrophod/) with karma: 277 on 2020-10-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4